# Poincare type inequality for functions with vanishing fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $f$ is also differentiable. Also assume that  $f'\in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for any $1\le p\le\infty$. Suppose that the Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(j)=0$ for all $|j|<n$. Show that $$\|f'\|_p\ge Cn\|f\|_p$$ for some constant $C$ independent of $f,p,n$.

My thought: If $f\in C^1(\mathbb{T})$, then it is easy to see that $\|f'\|_p\ge C\|f\|_p$ for some constant $C$. For the general case, should we approximate $f$ by trigonometric polynomials?

Comment: does "any" mean "every"? also, have u done it for trigonometric polynomials?

Comment: Is $f$ periodic ?

Comment: Generally I think if we say $f \in X(\mathbb{T})$ where $X$ is some function space then $f$ is periodic. That is a convoluted way of saying, functions on $\mathbb{T}$ are periodic.

Comment: @mathworker21 it is not too difficult to show for trig polynomials.  I can post that as part of an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @rubikscube09 i know. i was asking OP

Comment: Ok, just making sure.

Comment: @rubikscube09 oh, I didn't see you put bounty on this. is the difficulty going from trig poly's to everything (or maybe a different argument is needed)?

Comment: Well, the textbook that this is from (Muscalu-Schlag Vol. 1) suggests that a different argument is needed. They prove a bound $\|f''\|_p \geq Cn^{2}\|f\|_p$ by constructing a function in $L^1$ whose Fourier Series has coefficients $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and then show that if you convolve $f''$ with this new function, you recover $f$. They then apply Young's inequality to the convolution and the inequality is recovered.

Comment: The only issue is is that to build such a function with appropriate coefficients, one needs a result, and one of the assumptions of the result is that the coefficients are nonnegative + convex, which is not the case here.\

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the *Jackson inequalities*: 
$$
\|f-J_n*f\|_p\leq cn^{-1}\|f'\|_p,
\qquad
1\leq p<\infty,
$$
where $J_n$ is the *Jackson kernel*. This will immediately imply your inequality for $1<p<\infty$ by boundedness of the Fourier truncation (i.e., convolution with the Dirichlet kernel). I am not sure about the case $p=1$.